# How to Append a 2nd value to an existing key in a dictionary in Python in a Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working with an API in finance that will automatically update every time a specific time interval ends (ie every 30 minutes). It'll output a Timestamp as well as an Open, High, Low, and Close value.  What's happening behind the scenes of that API is a little above my paygrade so I'm trying my best to finesse the data to fit my needs.

Currently, when we are having it update 2 different markets (which would produce 2 different Close values, it seems to only have access to one markets values at a time.

Here is my code, every time a new bar is added, it'll print the close value with the Timestamp as the key.

```
def append(self, bar):
    symbols = symbol = ['CLE', 'RBE']
    bar_keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
    self.newest_bar = {key: getattr(bar, key) for key in bar_keys}
    self.bars[bar.Timestamp] = self.newest_bar

    # this is the line that i'd edit to append to the dictionary self.closes
    self.closes[bar.Timestamp] = bar.Close


    print(self.closes)
```

The problem is i'd like to have everything in one place. So:

How can i get the output from this:

```
{2019-07-17 15:11:00+00:00: 56.3}
{2019-07-17 15:11:00+00:00: 1.8719}
```

to this:

```
{2019-07-17 15:11:00+00:00: 56.3, 1.8719}
```

or better yet if I could nest each symbol as key with the value for each timestep:

```
{2019-07-17 15:11:00+00:00: 'CLE':56.3, 'RBE':1.8719}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the value a list like:

```
self.bars.setdefault('mykey', []).append('first_value') #  {'mykey': ['first_value']}
self.bars.setdefault('mykey', []).append('other_value') #  {'mykey': ['first_value', 'other_value']}
```

**Explanation:**

```
dictionary.setdefault(keyname, value)
```

> value: Optional.
>   If the key exist, this parameter has no effect.
>   If the key does not exist, this value becomes the key's value
>   Default value None

Comment: I get this error when I try that:AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: `mydict.setdefault('a', []).append('b')`  make sure you invoke append() properly

Comment: self.closes.setdefault(bar.Timestamp, []).append(bar.Close)

Comment: you mind taking one more look at this? still giving me an error @HaifengZhang